# Java Call Method of Class Object In Array

Tags: java, inheritance, methods

I have a class like so:

```
public abstract class Book {

    public abstract double retailPrice();

    private String title, author, ISBN;
    private double price;

    public Book() {
        title = "";
        author = "";
        ISBN = "";
        price = 0.00;
    }
    public Book(String title, String author, String ISBN, double price) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.ISBN = ISBN;
        this.price = price;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
}
```

With objects of a class `Textbook` (shown below) in an array:

```
public class Textbook extends Book {

    private String course;

    @Override
    public double retailPrice() {
        return super.getPrice() + (super.getPrice() * .10);
    }
    public Textbook() {
        course = "";
    }
    public Textbook(String course) {
        this.course = course;
    }
    public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }
    public void setCourse(String course) {
        this.course = course;
    }
}
```

My array is full of objects such as:

```
Book[] books = new Book[100];
books[i] = new Textbook(courseName);
```

When I call my array as using `books[i].` the only method available is `getTitle()` of Textbook's inherited class (Book).

So my question is, how do I get access to the `getCourse()` function of the Textbook class?

Answer (score 3):

If all elements of your `books` array are going to be `Textbook` instances, you can declare the array to be of type `Textbook books[]` instead of `Book[]`. Otherwise, you'll need to cast and, to be safe, you'll need to test the book type:

```
String course = null;
if (books[i] instanceof Textbook) {
    course = ((Textbook) books[i]).getCourse();
}
```

A variation is to skip the `instanceof` test and instead wrap the code in a `try/catch` statement to catch any `ClassCastException` that might be thrown. Of course, if you know by some other logic that `books[i]` must be an instance of `Textbook` you can safely eschew both the type check and the `try/catch` block.

Comment: Perfect. I do have other items than Textbooks so this works just as wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the array must have been created with type of Book.
Therefore, you must cast the object to TextBook to get the course:

```
String textBookCourse = ((Textbook) books[i]).getCourse();
```